# How can I delete rows in the main table that match the ID in my temp table?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my SQL code. In the delete section, the object "tblDeletes" that I declared in WITH statement gives me invalid object name, what could be wrong? thank you.

```
    USE [NEDB_beta]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[cms_cpAdminDeleteContentItemById]    Script Date: 12/13/2014 12:11:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cms_cpAdminDeleteContentItemById] 
@ID int
AS
BEGIN
WITH    tblDeletes AS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    [NEDB_beta].[dbo].[cms_tblContent]
        WHERE   ID = @ID -- this condition defines the ultimate ancestors in your chain, change it as appropriate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  c.*
        FROM    [NEDB_beta].[dbo].[cms_tblContent] as c
        JOIN    tblDeletes
        ON      c.intParentIdDraft = tblDeletes.ID
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    tblDeletes

DELETE FROM [NEDB_beta].[dbo].[cms_tblContent] 
WHERE ID IN 
    (SELECT ID 
     FROM tblDeletes);

END
```

Comment: I'm not sure the query makes sense. But you are referencing tbldeletes inside your tblDeletes definition. I also don't see you selecting parent IDs from child IDs. Additionally, you probably don't need to with at all. But I think the root of your problem is that you are referencing tblDeletes inside your with definition.

Comment: Because you are using CTE, and CTE's are defined only for one query. But here you are using same CTE. CTE scope get available only for one statement,you can not use it twice.

Comment: @tlbignerd that is how you write a recursive CTE.

Comment: Huh, thanks @Martin Smith, I haven't ever seen this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using CTE, and CTE's are defined only for one query. But here you are using same CTE. CTE scope get available only for one statement,you can not use it twice.

Remove the select statement, after CTE creation, I think thats not required, Because your main motive is delete the record.

But If you want to use `SELECT` statement, then either Repeat the CTE creation step or instead of CTE use Temp table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cms_cpAdminDeleteContentItemById] 
@ID int
AS
BEGIN
WITH    tblDeletes AS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    [NEDB_beta].[dbo].[cms_tblContent]
        WHERE   ID = @ID -- this condition defines the ultimate ancestors in your chain, change it as appropriate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  c.*
        FROM    [NEDB_beta].[dbo].[cms_tblContent] as c
        JOIN    tblDeletes
        ON      c.intParentIdDraft = tblDeletes.ID
        )

DELETE FROM [NEDB_beta].[dbo].[cms_tblContent] 
WHERE ID IN 
    (SELECT ID 
     FROM tblDeletes);

END
```

Comment: If they need the Select they can also `OUTPUT DELETED.*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Common Table Expression just in the statement that follows it. You already used it to `SELECT` from it. After that it doesn't "exists" anymore.